# Migration from Skype for Business on premises to Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, skype-for-business, lync

I would like to set up teams for our user teams in Office365. The users are synchronized to the Azure Active Directory via AD Connect.

With 2 users I could not set up teams, because "Interpreted User Type" is set to "HybridOnpremSfbUser". The other users are "DirsyncSfBUser" and so it works. I guess because these 2 users were once used to test a SfB on premises server. But this server does not exist anymore. Therefore Move-CSUser is not possible.

I have already removed the attributes that refer to the SfB server from the AD user object and synchronized them again, but without changing them.

Does anyone have a solution or an idea?

VG Marius

Answer (score 1):

Removing the Ad attributes and run adsync is the solution.
If it is not working. Please fallow below steps.
Delete the skype attributes for both AD accounts.
wait for the AD Replication.
check again AD accounts after replication. whether it is showing old attributes or new attributes. now do the adsync. 
Please check both users should have valid teams license. Now check users are showing in teams console.